# Editing cmakelists to include additional directories/cpp files?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, linker, cmake

I have a large amount of code, most of which was written by people working on this project before me. 
I think the problem is that I need to get the linker to link against the cppfiles, but I don't know how to do that using 'make' and Unix.. What do I do?

Maybe the problem is probably with the directories and libraries that are written in CMakeLists.txt.  I still get the undefined reference errors

Comment: What you posted above is not a CMakeList.txt, but rather a (generated) makefile.

Comment: CMake is used for generating makefiles - so the flow is normally 1. create `CMakeLists.txt`, 2. run `cmake` on `CMakeLists.txt` to generate a `Makefile`, 3. run `make` on the generated `Makefile`. To get you started, there's a tutorial for CMake here: http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Comment: I just listed the contents of the CMakeLists in the OP. My coworker only helped a little, but now expects me to solve this on my own